# Help needed with Repeated Measures ANOVA - how to correctly specify nested effect?

Tags: mixed-model, random-variable

I need some advice regarding nested effects.

My data set has the following variables:

*HeatingRate = dependent variable
Individual (n = 4) = fixed
Temperature gradient (n = 3) = fixed
Trial (n = 3 per temperature gradient per individual) = random*

I'm interested in knowing whether the heating rates differ between differ between temperature gradients and between individuals (not a random effect).

I'm, however, unsure how to correctly incorporate trial as a random effect (something I've been struggling with for a while...)

Can anyone tell me whether the nested effect is correctly specified?

```
lmer(HeatingRate ~ TemperatureGradient * Individual + (1|Individual|TemperatureGradient|Trial))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `TemperatureGradient` and `Individual` are your fixed effects that you are specifically interested in obtaining inferences for, and you have repeated measures within `Trial`, then the model should be:

```
HeatingRate ~ TemperatureGradient * Individual + (1|Trial)
```

Comment: @Chris Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not, please let us know why.